# Are there Sitecore e-commerce solutions that have native integration with SAP?

Tags: integration, sitecore-commerce

I'm looking for an Sitecore e-commerce solution that can read pricing/inventory information out of SAP. Has anyone done this before or know of a platform that can support this kind of integration natively?

Comment: You can integrate SAP thorough API with Sitecore. There is no 'out-of-the-box' connector that will do that. You would probably end up writing bunch of .NET web services code through which you can integrate product information.

Comment: I would like to point out that native integration is a rare thing. I have experience with connecting a CMS to Hybris e-commerce that was supported by a "Connector". Yet even this connector does not offer OOTB seamless connection.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

I think you'll need to look into writing integration code for this, as there would rarely be *anything* that completely OOTB connects two systems like these. So something like [Sitecore Commerce Connect](http://www.sitecore.net/products/sitecore-experience-platform/cross-channel-delivery/commerce) linked to [SAP Data Services](http://help.sap.com/bods) / [OData (discussed here)](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3929684).

That said; if by chance your client is using [SAP Hybris](https://www.hybris.com/en/), there does seem to be a tool on the market that might be of use. [EPAM Sitecore Commerce + SAP Hybris Connector](https://www.epam.com/ideas/brochures/epam-sitecore-commerce-sap-hybris-connector).

Comment: The first suggestion you gave is wrong in my opinion on the ETL part. Sitecores strength.